# Proving that $\rm dim range \,ST \le \min (dim range\, S, dim range\, T)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, linear-transformations

$U,V$ are finite dimensional vector spaces. $W$ is a given vector space. Let $T\in L(U,V), S\in L(V,W)$ be linear transformations then it is to be shown that $\rm dimrange  \,ST\le\min (dimrange\, T, dimrange \,S).$

**Proof:** For any $\rm x\in range \,ST, \exists y\in U$ such that $\rm STy=x$; and hence $\rm x=S(Ty)\in range \,S$. It follows that $\rm range\, ST\subset range\, S$, whence $$\rm dimrange \, ST\leq dimrange\ S.\tag 1$$

The following shows that $\rm dimrange \, ST\leq dimrange\, T$

Let $\rm v\in range\, T $. There exists a $u\in U$ such that $Tu=v$. It follows that $\rm STu= Sv\in range\, ST$.  The following map $\rm \overline S:range \, T\to range \,ST$ defined as $\rm \overline Sv=Sv$ for every $\rm v\in range T$ is a linear map.    By rank nullity theorem: $$ \rm dimrange\, T=dimnull \,\overline S+dimrange \, ST\ge dimrange \, ST.\tag 2$$

The result follows by $(1)$ and $(2)$.

Is my proof correct? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This looks right. Simply put, it seems the first part just says that since $Tu$ is a vector, $S(Tu)$ is clearly in the range of $S$. The second part is more complicated and is written in a slightly confusing way I feel. That being said, it is correct and simply says that your image will not "grow in dimension" by applying a linear transformation.

If you are willing to use that linearly independent sets are mapped to by linearly independent sets, then I prefer the following proof. Let $\{b_1,b_2,\cdots b_n\}$ be a basis for $range\, ST$. Then there is a linearly independent set $\{a_1,a_2,\cdots a_n\}$ in $V$ so that $S(a_1)=b_1,\cdots S(a_n)=b_n$, which means $\{a_1,a_2,\cdots a_n\}$ is in $range\, T$ (otherwise we wouldn't have $\{b_1\cdots n_n\}$ is $range\, ST$), giving the result. Clearly $\{b_1,b_2,\cdots b_n\}$ is also in the range of $S$, giving the first half as well. These aren't that different so it is just a matter of preference I think.

Comment: The second part in my post could be better put. The second part first shows that S takes every vector in range T into range ST. Then, $\overline S$ is defined as *the restriction of $S$ to range T. Then, rank nullity is applied on $\overline S$.

Comment: Thanks for the review. :)